# iTunes search URL on iOS 7 shows "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: search, app-store, ios7, itunes

The link itms-apps://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=DEVELOPERNAME works well on iOS 6.

But it will shows "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" on iOS 7, even the search bar is filled with the search term words.

How to fix it on iOS7? Thanks!

Comment: Hitting something similar to this, but for movie search. I am considering doing the search in my app via http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html and then displaying the results. Click on results would then launch iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this issue before,please try this link:
https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=DEVELOPERNAME